# create a user in Django 2.1 that is associated with an existing model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-authentication, django-users

In my `models.py` file I have the following code ->

```
from django.db import models

class Blogger(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
```

I want to associate the Blogger model with a User and create the User upon form submission. Here is the `forms.py` file ->

```
from django import forms
from blog.models import Blogger
class BloggerForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blogger
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password']
```

And here is the `views.py` ->

```
class BlogView(FormView):
    template_name = 'blogform.html'
    form_class = BloggerForm
    success_url = 'blog/'
```

How do I create a new user on the submission of this form ?

Comment: You add a `ForeignKey`, and use `request.user` to set the `user` of that `Blogger`. But it looks like it is better that you probably customize the user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: Furthermore the password should be hashed: do not store raw passwords (!).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by request.user. Is this done in the view when the form is saved ? Example -> `user=request.user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All fields in blogger already exists in User model, actually you don't need this Blogger model at all, just use the User model directly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I simply added `class Blogger(User):` after importing User from django and it works !

Comment: @jakuta  The User model is the core of Django project, a lot of other modules/apps will rely on it. Once you created your own user model, you'll need to adapt a lot of other stuff(you will understand what I mean when you go down this path further, and normally you will regret). In your case, it's totally unnecessary. Even you do have to extend/customize User model, best practice is to define an extra Profile model with a OneToOneForeignKey to builtin User, and define your new fields and methods there.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple ways you can do this but basically the general 2 answers are:

1. Toss/copy Django's user model and make your own (hard)
2. Extend the user model by making a new model, and relating it to the user model (easy)

I usually choose option #2 because then you don't have to reconfig the auth system. This is a good tutorial on how to do it: [simpleisbetterthancomplex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html)